# how to get data from url on asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, query-string

I want to get data from a url on asp.net. I need the data to be a string, which I can then use in other code.

```
http://example.com/service_name/videos/?category={0}&offset={1}&maxResult={2}
```

I need category offset and maxresult's number.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you talking about query string or a string in the format of a url?

Comment: ı think querry string.ı need just category ofset and max results's value.ı'm gonna use this value in sqlserver08's querry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string category = Request.QueryString["category"];
string maxResult = Request.QueryString["maxResult"];
```

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET QueryString Usage](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)